# Группировка и выбор строк, содержащих одно из значений

Tags: mysql, group-by

Здравствуйте. Что-то пятница похоже сказывается.

Есть таблица счетов на оплату (invoices) и их оплаты (payments). Один счет на оплату может быть оплачен несколькими платежами.

Таблицы:
*`invoices`* - `id` (int), ...
*`payments`* - `id` (int), `invoice_id` (int), `method` (enum Wire, PayPal, Webmoney) ...

Нужно получить invoices, содержащих например PayPal, но забрать нужно все payments.
Т.е.

```
 SELECT invoices.id AS invoice_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(payments.method) AS methods,
        ...
 FROM invoices

 LEFT OUTER JOIN payments
   ON payments.invoice_id = invoices.id

 GROUP BY invoices.id

 HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(payments.method) LIKE '%PayPal%'
```

В итоге получаем таблицу invoices и какими методами оплачена каждая запись.
UPD: добавит sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6a33d/1

Смущает LIKE в условии HAVING. Как обойтись без него в данном запросе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать двойной `JOIN`, чтобы отбросить инвойсы с другими платежами, но придется добавить `DISTINCT` на случай если один инвойс оплачен несколькими `PayPal` платежами:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   invoices.id AS invoice_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT payments.method ORDER BY payments.method SEPARATOR ', ') AS methods,
        ...
FROM invoices

JOIN payments p1
   ON p1.invoice_id = invoices.id


LEFT OUTER JOIN payments
   ON payments.invoice_id = invoices.id

WHERE p1.method = 'PayPal'

GROUP BY invoices.id
```

Comment: а что скажете на счет такого метода?     
  HAVING SUM(payments.method='PayPal')>0  
  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6a33d/14

Comment: Хороший вариант. Но возник вопрос, что при дублировании названий, должны ли они все выводиться в поле `methods`?

Comment: нет. В methods должны быть уникальные методы. Но я их фильтрую (уникализирую) перед выводом пользователю, так что как получится в запросе не очень важно.

Comment: Тогда надо исправить на `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT payments.method ORDER BY payments.method SEPARATOR ', ')` . [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad5f42/14/0)

Comment: @Ray Кстати, если процент оплат через PayPal не особо велик, то вариант с вторым join может оказаться эффективнее любых проверок в having. Если же велик - то наоборот

Comment: @Mike, спасибо. Пожалуй остановлюсь на двух джойнах.